# Most efficient way in Java to process text data as an Image object?

Tags: java, image

I was thinking about parsing through the source text to get the pixel data and then put them into an array of integers. How would I elegantly parse this data and pull out the pixel information without making it too expensive? Also, is this the most effective way of processing an image file with this format and returning it as an image object?

This is the structure of the plain text:

```
name
n m
px0,0 px0,1 … px0,m
px1,0 px1,1 … px1,m
pxn,0 pxn,1 … pxn,m
```

Example:

```
TestName
5 5
55, 6, 65, 79, 99
10, 25, 0, 45, 66
88, 19, 188, 76, 50
```

Comment: Can you be clearer on what you would like to do, would it be a matrix equivalent of letters?

Comment: have you tried anything yet that you think can be "too expensive" ??

Comment: Yes I am trying to process images in that format (read the file that contains that data) above and return it as an image object. I am contemplating how to read the data or what is the best way to get that data.

Comment: The option that I have done parses the text based on the first two lines being name and size, then followed by separation at the "," to extract the pixel data into an int[].

Comment: That sounds like the most reasonable approach. Unless you know of a problem, just go with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Parsing will take O(nm) anyway, since you need to parse all "pixels". Concerning elegance - you might probably look at Google Guava classes:

   - [CharStreams](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CharStreams.html)
   - [LineProcessor](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/LineProcessor.html)
   - [Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html)
2. Returning an "image" can be a good idea for compressing the data, but only if it's a lossless format (e.g. PNG).